# Can't resolve multiple constant drivers VHDL Error

Tags: vhdl

I am having an error related to multiple constant drivers in VHDL, and here i am uploading the image of the code............
In my code cmp is a component and  i want to use it in a for generate statement for a = Nx-Ny to a = 0..............But at

> a = Nx-Ny => tempx = ipx(Nx-1 downto Nx-Ny)
>   otherwise tempx = tempz(Ny-2 downto 0) & ipx(a)

For this i had used when - else statement but i am having error......

[image]

> Errors : Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "tempx[0]" at             ArrayDivider.vhd(44) (on the selected line in the image)
>   Error: Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

Please tell me what is the solution??????

Comment: How does your `Cmp` look like ? `tempx` goes into that component, does it cause the assignment to `tempx`? What does its entity declaration look like?

Comment: it's entity has 2 std_logic_vectors as input and 1 std_logic as output and a std_logic_vector as the second output............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have multiple drivers on tempx[0].

In the code you posted, there is only one conditional assignment to tempx.

However it is embedded in a `for ... generate` statement.

That means you are probably generating multiple copies of it, depending on the values of nx,ny. Hence the error.

EDIT

It doesn't help that you are posting an unreadably small picture instead of actual VHDL code. Please edit the question with your code.

Meanwhile I *think* I can see that you are generating a set of different modules (Cmp?) and feeding a different input signal to each.

However you **cannot** drive all these signals on the same signal at the same time! That is what the tools are telling you.
What you need is an **array** of signals, indexed by the generate variable, a.

```
subtype temp is std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
signal Tempx : array(Nx-Ny downto 0) of temp;
...

for a in ... generate
   tempx(a) <= (whatever expression you have now);
   Cmpa : generic map (...) port map (tempx(a), ...);
end generate;
```

Now, obviously, each member of the array has only one driver, eliminating the multiple driver errors.

Comment: But i need a for generate statement because i need tempx value to dependent on current value of a so i need it........

Comment: This is not a job for a generate statement; a process would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

be aware that your for/generate structure is not a loop! this statement leads to multiple implementations ((Nx-Ny)+1) of the logic you describe within the for/generate structure. therefore you do have multiple drivers for tempx. 
this was already mentioned in the comment here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586375/vhdl-error-related-to-concatination-of-variable)

Comment: Since i want tempx value to be dependent on the current value of a, and i want to use port map, which cnt be used in process........so i hv used for generate statement......now what shud i do as i need the loop......

Comment: as mentioned in the answer pointed at by the link above, write a for/loop statement into a process. however, as you saw correctly, a port map cannot be used within a process. therefore I suggest that you define a VHDL "procedure" that contains the logic from your component. a "procedure" can be called from inside a process.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to tempx, uses the same tempx for each loop. This results in multiple assignments to the same signal.
If you move the signal declaration into the generate block (between generate and begin) then you have a dedicated tempx signal for each loop.

```
for a in ... generate
   signal tempx : std_logic_vector(Ny-1 downto 0);
begin
   tempx <= (whatever expression you have now);
   Cmpa : generic map (...) port map (tempx, ...);
end generate;
```

The result is similar to the approach using an array.